# Why does Mongob shell allow document input of JSON without quotes?

Tags: json, mongodb

I'm teaching myself MongoDB and found I can enter JSON in the shell without quotes. Is this just for convenience or is there a JSON standard I'm unaware of?

ALLOWED IN MONGODB SHELL

```
{ 
    A:2
}
```

*.*.find() does return a valid JSON document
`{ "A":"2" }`

EDIT
correct return from shell input would be `{ "A":2 }`

JSON VALID

```
{
    "A": "1"
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid you've got it wrong - only key names are quoted by MongoDB shell.  If the value is 2 it is NOT going to return "2" as that would be a very different value.

Comment: thanks. I missed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While JSON does require quotes around object keys, JavaScript itself doesn't. The MongoDB shell uses JavaScript rather than requiring pure JSON.